# cant create app successful in react native FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

cant create app successful

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\newapp\android\local.properties'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 8s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not determine the dependencies of null. > SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\newapp\android\local.properties'. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 8s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Step 1. Go to the top of File Explorer and open drop-down
    Step 2. Now go to View > Hidden Items
    
    Add ANDROID_HOME to the Environment Variables if this doesn't work. Select Environment Variables -> System Properties -> Add Variable -> Enter Variable Name and Value.
    Step 1. Open System Properties
    Step 2. Select New and Insert Variable and Location
    Step 3. Add Variable name: ANDROID_HOME and value: as your SDK path.
    If your path is something else not in C Drive you have to add that. Make sure you enter the correct path UserName below is the name of your PC. and press OK.
    
    Now check the SDK location in your Android Studio and follow these steps.
    
    Step 1. Go to the FILE > SETTINGS
    Step 2. Search for SDK and place your SDK LOCATION.

Please take the actions listed below:

Navigate first to the android directory and then to your react-native project. Make a file called something like this:
local.real estate

Launch the file and enter the path to your Android SDK as shown below:
For those who utilise Windows:

sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk or (in IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio versions more recent than a certain one):

Where USERNAME is your PC user name, and sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk. Verify that the folder is sdk or Sdk as well.

For instance:

The path to the SDK is C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk.

C\:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk.dir=CSdk for Mac users:

/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk as sdk.dir
where your OSX username is USERNAME.

For users of Linux (Ubuntu):

= /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk; sdk.dir
where USERNAME is your Linux username (note that S in Sdk must match in case because Linux paths are case-sensitive).

Add the ANDROID_HOME variable to "Environment Variables" with the path C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk if this doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

your config ins't good, you should follow this => https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=windows&platform=android

Hope this help.

Comment: Step 1. Go to the top of File Explorer and open drop-down
Step 2. Now go to View > Hidden Items
Add ANDROID_HOME to the Environment Variables if this doesn't work. Select Environment Variables -> System Properties -> Add Variable -> Enter Variable Name and Value.
Step 3. Open System Properties
Step 4. Select New and Insert Variable and Location
Step 3. Add Variable name: ANDROID_HOME and value: as your SDK path.
If your path is something else not in C Drive you have to add that. Make sure you enter the correct path UserName below is the name of your PC. and press OK.